# How to view all the project files and its history that were manipulated inside git

Tags: git, gitkraken

How do I find all the history of the files that were tracked inside a git project including the deleted ones, I mean like the bIrds eye view of the project files because right now with the current status of the project, I think I have to just move all these into a new project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you have committed all your changes and you want to show only commit messages. Use:

  `git log --oneline -- path/to/folder`
- If you want to state the file(s) that have been modified and the number of lines that have been added/removed with the summary of modified files and lines that been added/removed. Use:

  `git log --stat -- path/to/folder`
- If you want to display info about the location of lines that have been modified with actual changes. Use

  `git log -p -- path/to/folder`

  Note: p stand for `patch` flag.
- If you want to view a specific commit among those of the commit of the specific folder. Use git show:

  `git show sha-of-the-specific-commit`

Now if you want to stat changes that have not been committed yet. You can use:

```
   git diff -- path/to/folder
```

I hope it is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Please use below command, in addition add -p to the below command to see the changes in the files.

```
git log -- path/to/folder
git log -- path/to/folder/*
```

if you want to use a graphic tool, such as gitk:

```
gitk -- path/to/folder
```

Comment: What i need is something that would show me all the history of the files and all the files that were tracked by git inside this git repository, mate..